# Clustering with a certain number of members

Tags: programming, data-structures, cluster-analysis

Is it possible to find exact number of clusters with *exact numbers of members in each cluster?*
Something like this:

```
data={1,2,1,1,3,2,2,3,2}

myClusters[data,{3,6}] -> {{1,1,1}, {2,2,2,2,3,3}}
myClusters[data,{2,4,3}] -> {{1,1}, {1,2,2,2}, {2,3,3}}
```

I guess the use of `FindClusters`, but any solution is possible (using Mathematica).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2};

Internal`PartitionRagged[Sort @ data, {3, 6}]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}}

```
Internal`PartitionRagged[Sort @ data, {2, 4, 3}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 3}}

Comment: ``Internal`PartitionRagged``, that's what I was looking for!!

Comment: Wow, an interesting package `Internal`! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

I'm a little uncertain as to exactly what you're asking for. Your 'clusters' are just sequential elements in your list.

Does this do what you want?

```
ListSplit[x_List, lengths_List] := 
  MapThread[Take[x, {##}] &, {Most[#], Rest[#] - 1}] &@Accumulate[Prepend[lengths, 1]]
```

Then simply:

```
ListSplit[Sort[data], {3, 6}]
ListSplit[Sort[data], {2,4,3}]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}}
>
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 3}}

Comment: The `ListSplit` code is courtesy of @Leonid Shifrin.

Answer (score 0):

```
myClusters = FoldPairList[TakeDrop, Sort @ #, #2]&;

myClusters[data, {3, 6}]
```

> {{1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3}}

```
myClusters[data, {2, 4, 3}]
```

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2, 2, 2}, {2, 3, 3}}